# Groovy Codenarc.xml org.xml.sax.SAXParseException xsi:schemaLocation not associated with element type ruleset not bound

Tags: exception, groovy, gradle, xsi, codenarc

I'm using Gradle 2.3 and project has Groovy code. For static code analysis, I'm using Codenarc (i.e. project folder has "config/codenarc/codenarc.xml" file).

In the build.gradle / GRADLE_HOME/init.d/top-level.gradle file, I have:

```
apply plugin: 'codenarc'

   codenarc {
     ignoreFailures = true
     configFile = file("config/codenarc/codenarc.xml")
   }
```

But while compiling this project, I'm getting the following error.

```
13:49:00 :codenarcAcceptanceTest UP-TO-DATE
13:49:01 :codenarcIntegrationTest FAILED
13:49:01 
13:49:01 FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
13:49:01 
13:49:01 * What went wrong:
13:49:01 Execution failed for task ':codenarcIntegrationTest'.
13:49:01 > org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 1; columnNumber: 173; The prefix "xsi" for attribute "xsi:schemaLocation" associated with an element type "ruleset" is not bound.
13:49:01 
13:49:01 * Try:
13:49:01 Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
13:49:01 
13:49:01 BUILD FAILED
```

**File contents in codenarc.xml file are:**

```
<ruleset xsi:schemaLocation="http://codenarc.org/ruleset/1.0 http://codenarc.org/ruleset-schema.xsd" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="http://codenarc.org/ruleset-schema.xsd">
   <description>Sample rule set</description>
   <ruleset-ref path="rulesets/basic.xml"/>
   <ruleset-ref path="rulesets/braces.xml">
      <rule-config name="IfStatementBraces">
         <property name="priority" value="3"/>
      </rule-config>
   </ruleset-ref>
   <ruleset-ref path="rulesets/concurrency.xml"/>
  <ruleset-ref path="rulesets/convention.xml"/>
   <ruleset-ref path="rulesets/design.xml"/>
   <ruleset-ref path="rulesets/dry.xml">
      <rule-config name="DuplicateStringLiteral">
         <property name="doNotApplyToClassNames" value="*Spec"/>
      </rule-config>
      <rule-config name="DuplicateNumberLiteral">
         <property name="doNotApplyToClassNames" value="*Spec"/>
      </rule-config>
      <rule-config name="DuplicateMapLiteral">
         <property name="doNotApplyToClassNames" value="*Spec"/>
      </rule-config>
      <rule-config name="DuplicateListLiteral">
         <property name="doNotApplyToClassNames" value="*Spec"/>
      </rule-config>
   </ruleset-ref>
   <ruleset-ref path="rulesets/exceptions.xml"/>
   <ruleset-ref path="rulesets/formatting.xml"/>
   <ruleset-ref path="rulesets/generic.xml"/>
   <ruleset-ref path="rulesets/grails.xml"/>
   <ruleset-ref path="rulesets/groovyism.xml"/>
   <ruleset-ref path="rulesets/imports.xml">
      <exclude name="MisorderedStaticImports"/>
   </ruleset-ref>
   <ruleset-ref path="rulesets/jdbc.xml"/>
   <ruleset-ref path="rulesets/junit.xml"/>
   <ruleset-ref path="rulesets/logging.xml"/>
   <ruleset-ref path="rulesets/naming.xml">
      <rule-config name="FieldName">
         <property name="ignoreFieldNames" value="log"/>
      </rule-config>
      <rule-config name="MethodName">
         <property name="doNotApplyToClassNames" value="*Spec"/>
      </rule-config>
      <exclude name="FactoryMethodName"/>
   </ruleset-ref>
   <ruleset-ref path="rulesets/security.xml">
      <exclude name="JavaIoPackageAccess"/>
   </ruleset-ref>
   <ruleset-ref path="rulesets/serialization.xml"/>
   <ruleset-ref path="rulesets/size.xml"/>
   <ruleset-ref path="rulesets/unnecessary.xml">
      <exclude name="UnnecessaryPackageReference"/>
   </ruleset-ref>
   <ruleset-ref path="rulesets/unused.xml"/>
</ruleset>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The xml did not know what `xsi` is you have add this as prefix from the correct namespace url. Try the following header:

```
<ruleset xmlns="http://codenarc.org/ruleset/1.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://codenarc.org/ruleset/1.0 http://codenarc.org/ruleset-schema.xsd"
    xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="http://codenarc.org/ruleset-schema.xsd">
```

Comment: agree, did the same to fix it. Here's the reason I got this issue. I "accidentally" used some beautification